# directory update to database tables code

Tags: php, mysql, database, directory

I have code that is supposed to scan through my database table and add new entries if it doesn't find matches to what was already there, so it is supposed to just add new entries and not duplicate any..

It works perfect the first day it is ran no matter how many times, but the next day it runs it adds anything new and duplicates all previous entries as the date no longer matches the supposed new entries it seems to think they are all new entries.

I have starred at the code too long and I can't figure out what I could add as a condition that would prevent this from happening.

Suggestions would be most appreciated!

```
<?php

// define directory path
$dir = "album";

function getDir($path = '.', $album_id = 0){

    // Directories to ignore when listing output. Many hosts
    // will deny PHP access to the cgi-bin.
    $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..' );

     // Open the directory to the handle $dir_handle
    $dir_handle = @opendir( $path );

    // Loop through the directory
    while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dir_handle ) ) ){
        // Check that this file is not to be ignored
        if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){
            // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down...
            if( is_dir( $path."/".$file ) ){
                //Check to see if we have this directory in the Album table
                $a_query = "SELECT * from albums where name = '".$file."' and ";
                $a_result = mysql_query($a_query);
                if (mysql_num_rows($a_result) >= 0){
                    //write this directory as a record
                    $a_insert_query = "INSERT INTO albums (`album_id` ,`name` ,`path` ,`image_id` ,`date`)
                                        VALUES (NULL ,'".$file."','".$path."/".$file."','0',NOW())";
                    $a_insert_result = mysql_query($a_insert_query);
                    //get the new album id
                    $album_id = mysql_insert_id();

                }else{
                    $a_row = mysql_fetch_array($a_result);
                    $album_id = $a_row["album_id"];
                }
                echo $file."<br/>";

                // Re-call this same function but on a new directory.
                // this is what makes function recursive.
                 getDir( $path."/".$file, $album_id );

            } else {//if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){
                //this is a file  -- handle reading the file names
                $file_name_array = explode(".",$file);
                $file_type = strtolower($file_name_array[count($file_name_array)-1]);
                switch($file_type){
                    case "jpg":
                    case "jpeg":
                    case "gif":
                    case "png":
                            echo "-->".$file."<br/>";
                            $img_query = "SELECT `album_id`, `name`, `path`, `image_id` from images where path = '".$path."/".$file."'";
                            $img_result = mysql_query($img_query);
                            if (mysql_num_rows($img_result) >= 0){
                                $p_query = "INSERT INTO `images` (`image_id` ,`name` ,`path` ,`album_id` ,`date`)
                                            VALUES (NULL ,  '".$file."',  '".$path."/".$file."','".$album_id."',NOW())";
                                $p_result = mysql_query($p_query);
                            }
                    break;
                }
            }// else {//if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){
        }//if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){

    }//while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dir_handle )

}

//this function call starts the process.  
//The function recursively calls itself to step down through the directories.
//the second argument is the album id

getDir($dir, 0);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're checking for an existing record with `if (mysql_num_rows($a_result) >= 0){`, that will evaluate to `TRUE` whether the record is there or not. Is that really what you want? If you only want to write to the DB when the record doesn't exist, then use:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($a_result) < 1){
```

You also have a syntax error on your first $a_query - `$a_query = "SELECT * from albums where name = '".$file."' and ";`  - the `and` at the end shouldn't be there.

Comment: I took out the syntax error just after I submitted this, it was part of my trying to figure out how to get this to work, I tried that suggestion with changing the 0 to a 1, same result when I changed the date to a previous date on my albums.. the old ones are still added as if its thinking its a new entry cause of the date..
It won't add the duplicate entries on the same day, it has to be a previous date stamp to enter the same album again..

Not sure what I can do to prevent this, but it will make linking clients to albums difficult if I can't resolve this one

Comment: Did you also change the `>=` to a `<`?

Comment: Oh goodness, I had not.. I think that may have done it!! 

I am still a serious newbie to this stuff, so troubleshooting it is really hard for me, but I genuinely appreciate this help!!